# Multiple TableLayouts inside a LinearLayout - Android

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I am attempting to place multiple `TableLayout`s inside of a `LinearLayout`.  When I implemented the code and ran it, the display was my background image with nothing displayed on it.  Not sure what happened.

Before I tried to do this, I had everything displaying correctly but it was so much text that it had to be extremely small to make everything fit.  To fix this I want to do 3 `TableLayout`s with the middle one being a `ScrollView` (I will worry about implementing the `ScrollView` after I fix the problem at hand).

My question is how to make all 3 `TableLayout`s visible with each being a specific percentage of the screen.

Below is 100% of the code for this XML file.

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll" >    

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="15" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/points"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".25"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:gravity="left" 
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/percentage"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".3"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/total_score"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".45"
                        android:textSize="7sp"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#000001" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/answerColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/verseColumn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="70" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q1Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q1Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q2Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q2Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q2Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q2Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row6"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q3Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q3Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q3Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q3Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row7"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q4Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q4Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q4Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q4Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row8"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q5Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q5Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q5Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q5Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q6Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q6Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q6Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q6Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row10"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q7Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q7Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q7Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q7Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row11"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q8Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q8Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q8Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q8Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row12"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q9Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q9Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q9Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q9Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row13"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/q10Image"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q10Question"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".45"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q10Answer"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/q10Verse"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:textSize="7sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="15" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".34"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want the tables to be side by side, or on top of eachother?  You have the orientation of your LinearLayout set to "vertical" now, but the width of each table as "0dip".  I imagine you want them side by side, which means the orientation of the LinearLayout should be "horizontal", and keep your table widths as "0dip".  If you do in fact want them on top of eachother, change the width for each table to "wrap_content" or "match_parent" and the height to "0dip".

**Vertical example**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="15" >
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="70" >
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="15" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Horizontal Example**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Bottom table edit**

```
   <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="15" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1" >

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/mainmenuBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />

            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/highscoresBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/playBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="7sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: I want the 3 ````TableLayouts```` actually to be on top of each other -- not side by side.  I want the top one to be approximately 15% of the screen and also the botoom one to be about 15%.  The middle ````TableLayout```` is going to be the remainin 70% and be wrapped with a ````ScrollView````.  I do not have time at this moment to review the code you put above, but I will later tonight.

Comment: take a look a the edit i made to the vertical example to set specific weights for each table. when you add the ScrollView, you will want to set the table height to wrap content, the ScrollView height to 0dip and ScrollView weight to 70.

Comment: It worked.. sort of.  The top ````TableLayout```` is viewable and proportional.  The middle ````TableLayout```` is viewable, proportional and scrollable.  But the bottom ````TableLayout```` is not viewable.  There is room for the bottom ````TableLayout```` so the room has been allocated for it on the screen, but it is not viewable.  I have updated my opening post with my up to date code.

Comment: see my update above. i'm not sure about how stretchColumns will play with weights, you may have to remove one or the other.